# Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type. Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

estoy haciendo un programa para ventas, el cual esta conectado a una base de datos SQLite3. Estoy haciendo algo parecido a lo que hizo alguien en youtube. Pero mi diferencia es que mi programa quiero que muestre el id y el importe. Aca dejo todo el codigo y los errores que me salen.

```
    def delete_product(self):
    self.mesagge['text'] = ''
    try:
        self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][0]
    except IndexError as e:
        self.mesagge['text'] : 'Selecciona un importe'
        return
    self.mesagge['text'] = ''
    name = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values']
    query = 'DELETE FROM importes WHERE id = ?'
    self.run_query(query, (name, ))
    self.mesagge['text'] = 'El importe fue eliminado'
    self.get_products()
```

[image: Aqui esta el error]

Espero que me puedan ayudar!

Y este es el programa
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo que me sale es el importe, porque puse values. Como tendria que hacer para que se seleccione el id asi poder eliminarlo?

Comment: Y si, es una lista!

Comment: y en el codigo original, del youtuber, no pone 'values', el pone 'text' pero porque tiene name y price

Comment: Y como seria? con un for? soy nuevo programando jaja

Comment: Es la columna 0.

Comment: Y si pongo 'text' en vez de values, me sale TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Con solo sacar el [0] del try me funciono. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Lucas he creado una respuesta resumiendo mis comentarios y explicando algo mejor como funciona el método item. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error original lo causa `sqlite3.Connection.cursor.execute` y se debe a que se le pasa como parámetro a la query una lista o tupla anidada, lo cual solo es posible usar con `sqlite3.Connection.cursor.executemany` de forma que cada anidamiento seria una consulta.

Cuando se obtiene una fila de un `ttk.TreeView` mdeiante el método `ttk.TreeView.item` se obtiene un diccionario de la forma:

```
{'text': 1, 'image': '', 'values': [75, 8], 'open': 0, 'tags': ''}
```

lo relevante para el contenido de las celdas son:

- **La clave `"text"`**: almacena el texto de la primera columna (identificada siempre con `#0`).
- **La clave `"values"`**: almacena el valor del resto de columnas y es siempre una lista si hay al menos una fila seleccionada, si no es una cadena vacía..

Cuando haces:

```
name = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values']
```

`name` es una lista y por eso `execute` llora amargamente... Para obtener el  valor de una columna en concreto, que no sea la primera, debes indizar:

```
name = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][0]
```

ésto obtendría el valor de la segunda columna del TreeView.

Por lo tanto, si tu columna con las ids es la primera debes hacer:

```
name = self.tree.item(tree.selection())['text']
```